# how to right test cases of switch cases using angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a situation where I want to write test cases of this code using angular , please help

```
export type Browser = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F' | 'Unknown';

export function detect(): Browser {
  const agent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
  switch (true) {
    case agent.indexOf('A') > -1:
      return 'Edge';
    case agent.indexOf('B') > -1 && !!(<any>window).opr:
      return 'Opera';
    case agent.indexOf('C') > -1 && !!(<any>window).chrome:
      return 'Chrome';
    case agent.indexOf('D') > -1:
      return 'IE';
    case agent.indexOf('E') > -1:
      return 'FF';
    case agent.indexOf('F') > -1:
      return 'Safari';
    default:
      return 'Unknown';
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the tag angularJs please, also, where is this file located? is it in a component? a service? a generic typescript file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: it is a component file @Andres2142

Comment: What is your testing framework?  Jest?  Jasmine?  Something else?

Comment: jasmine @mrrogers

Comment: What is the hard thing to test?  Are you asking how to mock `window`?  or how to write a test using `jasmine`?  I agree with @Andres2142 - this question isn't really about angularjs.  It's just about how to test a javascript function.

Comment: how to write a test using jasmine @mrrogers

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
// my_spec.ts
//
import { detect } from "./the-file.ts"

describe("detect", function() => {

  it("when the browser is 'A' - it returns Edge", () => {
    jasmine.createSpy('window.navigator.userAgent').and.returnValue('A')
    expect(detect()).toEqual('Edge');
  });

  it("when the browser is 'B' - it returns Opera", () => {
    jasmine.createSpy('window.navigator.userAgent').and.returnValue('B')
    expect(detect()).toEqual('Opera');
  });

  ...

});
```

https://jasmine.github.io/

I don't have jasmine up so I was unable to test this out but I think it should be close to right.